# Pandas Grouping - Row counts of groups within a group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This is the first time I've asked a question here, so let me know if more info is needed -

I currently have a pandas `df` that is grouped by three *columns*:

```
# Group by employee, end of work date and calendar date sum the quantity of the hours on each calendar date
empHoursSum = df.groupby(['Employee ID', 'Week Ending', 'Calendar Date'])['Quantity'].sum().to_frame('Quantity')
```

This gives me an `Employee ID` with buckets for `Week Ending` (date the calendar work week ends) and `Calendar Date` with the date's associated hours summed.
[image]

What I am wanting to see is a running count for each `Calendar Date` within a `Week Ending` group.

For instance if someone worked 6 days in a work week there would be 6 rows of dates. I would like to see a column with a 1 on the first entry a 2 on the second entry, so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

You can group by the 0th and 1st levels (the two "outermost" levels) of  `empHoursSum`, get the cumulative counts with `.cumcount()`, and assign these counts to a new column, adding 1 to start the counts at 1 instead of 0:

```
empHoursSum['running_count'] = empHoursSum.groupby(level=[0, 1]).cumcount() + 1
```

Comment: @CameronHunt, very glad to hear that!

Comment: I've got another question regarding this if you're able to answer.

In the example above - Is it possible to have a running sum of all the quantities in 'Week Ending' Level by employee?

I'm basically trying to see a sum of all the hours in a given work week.

Comment: @CameronHunt, I haven't tested this, but it should work: `empHoursSum['running_sum'] = empHoursSum.groupby(level=[0, 1])['quantity'].cumsum()`

Comment: You pull through once again! Thank you Peter!